# Undefined Reference to `pthread_init' When Using -lpthread Flag:

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads

I'm compiling using:

`gcc -o outfile infile.c -lpthread`

and the only undefined reference is `pthread_init`.

I have tried using `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, as per some suggestions online.

I **am** including `<pthread.h>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call `pthread_init()`.  It's not necessary on Linux.

Comment: Don't - early implementations of pthreads needed it, so you find it in tutorials.  What's a bit of a mystery to me is that there's not much out there that outright tells you don't need it anymore - it's just not mentioned in newer docs.

Comment: No. I knew this some time ago. But, I suppose it's easy to forget!